# Three webapps directories in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When you run Tomcat from Eclipse, there are up to three webapps directories:

1. $CATALINA_BASE/webapps, i.e., Eclipse's webapps, e.g., `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/webapps`
2. wtpwebapps, e.g., `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps`
3. The webapps in the "Tomcat installation directory" ($CATALINA_HOME)

Can someone summarize the difference between them? In particular, in which webapps directory does Tomcat look for war files and web pages?

(Also see [this similar question about conf directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77233922/three-conf-directories-for-tomcat).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Tomcat loads webapps from #1 and #2, but not #3.

Longer answer:

1. Tomcat treats `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` as its webapps directory. It will expand any war file placed in this directory (if configured to expand wars).
2. People usually say that `wtpwebapps` is the staging directory used by Eclipse. But the contents of this directory are never copied to `webapps`, rather, Eclipse tells Tomcat to load certain apps from `wtpwebapps`. For example, if in Eclipse you add a project called "MyProject" to Tomcat, the file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` will include a line like this:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProject" path="/MyProject" ... >
```

3. When run in Eclipse, Tomcat completely ignores the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` directory.